# Word file downloaded from browser tab with incorrect file name

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open a `.docx` file on browser but it gets downloaded. This is fine but the downloaded `.docx` file name is incorrect.

I am using Chrome browser and ASP.NET C# code.

Suppose the file is in network path `//test/test.docx` and aspx file name `DownloadTest.aspx` which has the download word doc code. When it gets downloaded, the file name is `DownloadTest.docx` and not `test.docx`.

Below is the code.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    string filePath = Request.QueryString["FN"];
    Page.Title = filePath;

    this.Response.ClearContent();
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition;", "attachment;filename=" + Request.QueryString["FN"]);

    this.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    this.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of your query string parameter `FN` to the network file name (test.docx). The `Content-Disposition` header determines the file name in the browser when downloaded.

In other words, that header needs to be

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.docx
```

So your code should be

```
this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fn);
```

Where fn is equal to test.docx, which may not be the request param. It's a good idea to always check the request parameter values and validate them before doing anything with them.

Also notice that when you add the header, don't put a semicolon after its name.